# inputStreamReader no quiere importar: lanza error

Tags: java

Este `inputStreamReader` no quiere importar, lanza error en el editor. Utilizo Netbeans.

```
 private static Integer retornoNumero ( ) throws IOException{

     InputStreamReader capturarTeclado = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
       BufferedReader buffer =  new BufferedReader(capturarTeclado); 
       String stringnumero = buffer.readLine( );
       Integer  numero = Integer.parseInt(stringnumero);
      
       return numero ;  
    
     };
```

Comment: que error? importaste las librerias? si estas lanzando una exception usaste un try- catch cuando usas el metodo retornoNumero()??

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe el error que estás teniendo. No olvides mostrar un [repro]: ¿estás realmente importando lo que corresponde?

Comment: si lanze  una IOException no un try catch

Comment: Leé de vuelta lo que te dijo @Dramaturgo: al llamar al método _retornoNumero_, ¿estás haciendo un `try - catch`? En tu método específicamente estás diciendo que puede lanzar un `IOException`. De nuevo: pulsá en [edit] y mostrá un [repro].

Comment: gracias ya puede solucionar el problema

Answer (score 0):

No sé si falta código, pero para que funcione tienes que completar un poco más la declaración del método.
‘’’

```
private static Integer retornoNumero() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader capturarTeclado = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(capturarTeclado);
        String stringNumero = buffer.readLine();
        Integer numero = Integer.parseInt(stringNumero);
    
        return numero;
    }
```

‘’’

También te recomiendo usar la nomenclatura correcta que también te dejo

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).